# Why is the error ORA-01008 appearing?

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, spring-integration

I´ve got a query in spring integration that it´s mapped but when I run my query I get the error: ORA-01008 not all variables were bind.

Here is my spring integration code:

```
<bean id="cAlarmaMapper" class="com.praxis.desvucem.alarms.jdbc.ContactoAlarmaRepositorioMapper" />


<jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="consultaClavesAlarma" channel="alarmChannel" data-source="dataSource"
                query="SELECT cAlarma.CON_CANAL
                       FROM MF_C_CONTACTO_ALARMA  cAlarma WHERE cAlarma.CON_ALARMA_CLAVE in(:payload.clave)"
                row-mapper="cAlarmaMapper" max-rows-per-poll="${database.alarms.registros.consulta}">
</jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

and here is my mapper code:

```
public class ContactoAlarmaRepositorioMapper implements RowMapper<MfCContactoAlarma> {

  public MfCContactoAlarma mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    MfCContactoAlarma contacto = new MfCContactoAlarma();
    contacto.setConCanal(rs.getString("CON_CANAL"));
    return contacto;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my payload wasn´t getting info. So after I put data into my payload. It started working.